# What is the correct way of keeping spaces, Latin and Cyrillic characters with preg_replace, in PHP 7.4.*?

Tags: regex, php-7.4

Consider the following.

```
function cleanText($text) {
    return preg_replace("/[^0-9\p{Latin}\p{Cyrillic}\.\-\_\s+]+/u","",$text);
}
$tmp = "intro_|_text  Mary had a little lamb, we'll be right back   123456789  абвгдђежзијкл     ,./'*     αβγδε    šđ";
echo cleanText($tmp);
```

Expected output is (as seen on both phpfiddle.org, and repl.it):

```
intro__text Mary had a little lamb well be right back 123456789 абвгдђежзијкл . šđ
```

However, Xampp with PHP 7.4.8, and [this site](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/) return the following (the latter with every PHP 7.4.*):

```
aMaryhadalittlelambwellberightback123456789абнллклл.šđ
```

If `\p{Latin}\p{Cyrillic}` is removed, the spaces are kept. What would be the correct way of having both single spaces and the specific alphabets inside `preg_replace`?

Comment: For some reason, these properties are not supported, you may use `\p{L}` to match any letter, use `preg_replace('/[^0-9\\p{L}\\s._+-]+/u', '', $text)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Are there any caveats when going with `\p{L}`? That is to say, are there any special cases where it might fail or behave unexpectedly?

Comment: It just matches any letter. If you do not care if it is an Armenian, or Cyrillic, or Hebrew letter, then you may use it.

Comment: This seems to be working. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `\p{L}` instead of the the Unicode properties whose support seems to be broken here.

You can use

```
preg_replace('/[^0-9\\p{L}\\s._+-]+/u', '', $text)
```

Also note that it is safer to use `-` at the end of the character class, so as not to escape it. `.` and `_` do not need escaping either, `_` is a word char and `.` loses its special meaning inside a character class.