# modify javascript regex with cirilian and latin language in urls and email

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, url, hyperlink

I need to validate cyrillic and latin regular alphabet encoded urls, this is my current regex:

```
    let final = text;
  const divElement = document.createElement('div');
  // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
  const linkRegExp = /\b(((http(s)?:\/\/)([\w-]{1,32}(\.|\:)[\w-]{1,32}))|([\w-]{1,32}(\@)[\w-]{1,32}(\.)[\w-]{1,32})|([\w-]{1,32}(\.)[A-Za-z]{1,32}))\b/gi;

  function replacer(url) {
    if (url.match(/\S+@\S+\.\S+/ig)) {
      const email = document.createElement('a');
      email.innerHTML = url;
      email.href = `mailto:${url}`;
      email.setAttribute('class', 'email');

      return `${email.outerHTML}`;
    }
    const link = document.createElement('span');
    link.innerHTML = url;
    link.setAttribute('class', 'link');
    link.setAttribute('style', 'color: blue; cursor: pointer');

    return `${link.outerHTML}`;
  }

  final = final.replace(RegExp(linkRegExp), replacer);
```

I need to validate urls like яндекс.рф. or стопкоронавирус.рф
pls help!

At the moment, I can identify any email or link, but only in Latin. I tried to replace [\w-] with [\wа-я-] and so on, but this all doesn’t suit me for some reason, maybe somewhere there is an error in the expression

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63428222) might help. You would need to adapt it for your use case, since you're checking the URL validity. This - `\p{L}` - is the key part, and it would be used instead of your `A-Za-z`.

Comment: i tried this but it didn't work, i also tried `A-Za-zА-Яа-я`

Comment: Not sure if your question will be reopened, so I can't really post this as an answer, but take a look at [this](https://regex101.com/r/c3NJ9f/1). The explanations are in the upper-right part of that website. I've used the `m` / multiline flag, to check for multiple links / email addresses at once. If you're checking them one by one (for example, in a loop), you could remove the `m` flag, and just use `gi` (greedy, case-insensitive).

Comment: I don't know why but it doesn't work for me

Comment: Is it not working in your code, or in the link I posted?

Comment: Maybe in my code, I have attached a screenshot of the full code